# How to automate logging in and retrieve data?

Tags: http, automation, sniffing

I want to automate logging into a website and retrieving certain data.
I thought the way to do this would be to sniff the HTTP requests so I know where the login form is being POSTed to so I can do the same using NodeJS/Java/Python.

However I can't seem to find the HTTP request that handles it.
The site seems to use some Java-applet and a lot of Javascript.

This is the site: [link](https://ppair.uspto.gov/TruePassSample/AuthenticateUserLocalEPF.html)

Should I have a different approach?
Also also wonder about storing a cookie session, and sending it with each HTTP request after logging in.

I'm sorry if I am not to clear, I will try to explain myself further and edit this post if needed.

Comment: [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the developer console (hit F12) in Chrome (this works also in other browsers) and then click the "Network" tab. There you see all network calls.

To detect what http requests are performed from a mobile device, you can use a proxy like [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Also be aware that if you post from nodejs the cookies won't be set in the users browser.